# Is there a unix command line utilty for 'mapping' by line?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, utilities

I have an input stream, and I want to "map" to output lines. For instance, if my input stream were the files nums, I'd want that this syntax

```
$ cat nums
9534
2343
1093
7023
$ cat nums | map ./myscript $0
```

would be equivalent to

```
$ echo 9534 | ./myscript
$ echo 2343 | ./myscript
$ echo 1093 | ./myscript
$ echo 7023 | ./myscript
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `xargs` is the closest thing to your hypothetical `map`:

```
cat nums | xargs -n1 ./myscript
```

or

```
cat nums | xargs -n1 -J ARG ./myscript ARG
```

or

```
cat nums | xargs -I ARG ./myscript ARG
```

Unfortunately, `xargs` doesn't let you invoke things that read from stdin, so you'd have to rewrite your script to accept a command-line argument rather than reading from stdin.

Comment: Specifically, I have a text file where most lines are IP addresses, and for each one, I want to execute a wget command and replace that line of text with the response text from wget.

Comment: Ah, cool! I didn't know you could use the `-n1` switch to limit the number of arguments per line.

Comment: You might also want to look at GNU parallel, which is not a standard UNIX utility, but is similar to `xargs`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_(software)

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
  "$@" <<< "$line"
done
```

Comment: Indeed, a simple script would do what I'm talking about. I was curious, though, if a command line utility exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bash script to do this.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="| ./myscript"

echo "9534 $string"
echo "2343 $string"
echo "1093 $string"
echo "7023 $string"
```

Or, you could easily fill an array with your numerical values and just do this all in one loop.

Comment: I know, but I was hoping for a way to parse by line.

Comment: I know that there used to be old text-based command-line games that did something like what you're talking about.
Also, I suppose, VI and EMACS must be able to do what you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like:

```
$ cat nums | parallel -N1 --pipe ./myscript
```

which is equivalent to

```
$ echo 9534 | ./myscript
$ echo 2343 | ./myscript
$ echo 1093 | ./myscript
$ echo 7023 | ./myscript
```

Or you can do:

```
$ cat nums | parallel ./myscript
```

which is equivalent to

```
$ ./myscript 9534
$ ./myscript 2343
$ ./myscript 1093
$ ./myscript 7023
```

The jobs will run in parallel (one job per core) until all jobs are done.